# How can I make the table text not overlap the next column

Tags: tables

I'm trying to format a table to look like this: [image: what the table is supposed to look like]

This is the code that I've written for it:

```
\documentclass{article}

%Table formatting
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1} #1\ignorespaces}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{table} [ht]
    \centering
    \label{tab:test}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{$c^c^p{0.9in}^c^c^c^c}
        \hline 
        \rowstyle{\bfseries}ID & Requirement & Description & Inputs & Expected outputs & Pass/Fail & Comments \\
        \hline
        A1.1 & FR1 & \multirow{2}{0.9in}{checking attendants can only park certain vehicles} & 1-3 & Nothing & P & \\ 
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}                                                  & 4-5 & produces error & F & doesn't check input of vehicleType \\
            \hline
        A1.2 & FR2 & \multirow{2}{0.9in}{checking attendants can only park certain vehicles} & 1-3 & Nothing & P & \\
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}                                                  & 4-5 & produces error & F & doesn't check input of vehicleType \\

    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{Test table}
\end{table}
```

The current output is causing the text in the description to overlap into the next row. I'm aware that there have been similiar questions asked but I'm new to LaTeX and don't understand how their solution fixed the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should never use `adjustbox` with tabless, as it can produce inconsistent font sizes. It's better to play with the font size and the value of `\tabcolsep`.

This being said, you can use multirow, not in column 3, but in columns 4-7 instead.

To fit `\textwidth` I suggest using `tabularx`, columns 3 and 7 being of type `X`. In this case, you have to use `\multirow` only for columns 4-6. Also, I loaded geometry, to have more sensible margins (if you don't need marginal notes). Last, I used the rules from `booktabs`, to add some vertical padding around horizontal lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

%Table formatting
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1} #1\ignorespaces}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}


\begin{table} [!htb]
    \centering\renewcommand{\cellalign}{tc}
    \label{tab:test}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{$c^c^p{0.9in}^c^c^c^c}
        \toprule
        \rowstyle{\bfseries}ID & Requirement & Description & Inputs & Expected outputs & Pass/Fail & Comments \\
        \midrule
        A1.1 & FR1 & \RaggedRight checking attendants can only park certain vehicles & \makecell{1-3\\4-5} & \makecell{Nothing\\produces error} & \makecell{P \\F }& \makecell{\\doesn't check input of vehicleType}\\
        \midrule
        A1.2 & FR2 & \multirow{2}{=}{checking attendants can only park certain vehicles} & 1-3 & Nothing & P & \\
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & 4-5 & produces error & F & doesn't check input of vehicleType \\[8ex]
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{Test table}
\end{table}

\begin{table} [! htb]
    \centering\footnotesize\renewcommand{\cellalign}{tc}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \label{tab:test}
     \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{$c^c^X^c^c^c^X}
        \toprule
        \rowstyle{\bfseries}ID & Requirement & Description & Inputs & Expected outputs & Pass/Fail & Comments \\
        \midrule
        A1.1 & FR1 & \RaggedRight checking attendants can only park certain vehicles & \makecell{1-3\\4-5} & \makecell{Nothing\\produces error} & \makecell{P \\F }&\mbox{} \newline doesn't check input of vehicleType \\
            \midrule
        A1.2 & FR2 & \multirow{3}{=}{\RaggedRight checking attendants can only park certain vehicles} & 1-3 & Nothing & P & \\
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & 4-5 & produces error & F & doesn't check input of vehicleType \\%[8.5ex]
\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Test table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to add lines in between the \multirow cells?

Comment: Do you mean vertical lines?

Comment: No, horizontal lines in between the data from the inputs column to the end column.

Comment: You can use  `\hline` or `midrule` in `makecell, but it will be *inside* the `\makecell` contents. Inside `X` column, you can use `\hrule`. Is that enough for your needs?

Comment: yes Thank you very much.